# How to run multiple update statements in TOAD for Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I have about 800 update statements I want to run in TOAD

```
UPDATE my_table SET col1 = 'a' WHERE col2 = '1';
UPDATE my_table SET col1 = 'b' WHERE col2 = '2';
UPDATE my_table SET col1 = 'c' WHERE col2 = '3';
UPDATE my_table SET col1 = 'd' WHERE col2 = '4';
```

I have tried:

- hitting F5
- selecting all and hitting F5
- wrapping my statements in:

  ```
  BEGIN
  (update statements)
  END;
  /
  ```

all to no avail. It pops up the processing window and says 1 of 800... and never completes even the first statement.

F9 will complete the first statement but nothing else. Any ideas? TOAD v11.5.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried hitting F5, selecting all and hitting F5, wrapping my statements in:

You don't need to wrap the **UPDATE statements** within **BEGIN-END block**. Simply do **Execute as Script** or **Press F5** with all the update statements in the same worksheet.

Comment: yeah. I tried that - just the update statements one per line with     ; at the end of each line. still not working

Comment: You said you wrapped them in a PL/SQL block. Did you try only with the update statements? Select all and then execute as script or press F5.

Comment: a) In general as pointed allready out it should work, you could check your Toad-Options for a command delimiter...I couldn't find anything. b) It _might_ be, that the dataset you want to update with your first update is locked by another session.

Comment: @evilive thank you. There was a db lock and once the DBA cleared it, it worked fine.